# settings in apache for django app which need ssl for some pages

Tags: django, ssl, apache2

My django app (let me call it `partlysecureapp`)has an index page which is visible to all.All the other pages (reachable from links on index page) need the user to log in. I want to use the app with SSL in apache2.

I already have an app(say `mysecureapp`) deployed on apache with SSL, which has all pages needing login by the user. I have set the configurations for this as follows.

My apache2 is at `/etc/apache2` which has the following directory structure.

```
/etc/apache2/
            |--conf.d---*charset,security,localized-error-pages* 
            |---mods-available---...
            |---mods-enabled---...
            |---sites-available---default,default-ssl,ssl
            |---sites-enabled---shortcut to ssl
            |---apach2.conf
            |---httpd.conf
            |---ports.conf
            |---magic
            |---envvars
```

For the `secureapp`, I have set this in file `sites-available/ssl`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/dev/python/django/mysecureapp

        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +StrictRequire
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    ...
    WSGIScriptAlias /mysecureapp /home/dev/python/django/mysecureapp/mysecureapp.wsgi
    Alias /site_media/ /home/dev/python/django/mysecureapp/media/

</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly..

To deploy my `partlysecureapp`,

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/partlysecureapp/` need to show index page which is accessible to all.
but

```
../partlysecureapp/link1/
../partlysecureapp/link2/
../partlysecureapp/link3/
```

require login and should be served through ssl .

I think, I need to add another `WSGIScriptAlias` for my `partlysecureapp`. Do I need to add another `DocumentRoot` for the `partlysecureapp`? How to tell apache to serve the index page from port `8080` and others through ssl port?

As of now the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is blank. Only the `sites-available/ssl` file has a `VirtualHost` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let's separate the concerns here: one thing is to require login, other is to require SSL. The former is specific to Django, and should be handled in your views; and for the latter, IMHO you should consider the possibiilty of serving **everything** through SSL, that would simplify your setup a lot. Sure, there's some overhead, and it's up to you to decide whether it matters or not for your particular case.

That said, for your proposed scenario:

1. To serve **anything** from plain HTTP, you need to listen to the port `80` (or, in your case, `8080`). So you need a separate `VirtualHost` bound to that port, with a separate WSGI application for itself.
2. To allow a single path (your index file) from this virtual host, but require everything else to be served by the SSL protected one, you can use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/partlysecureapp$ - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) https://127.0.0.1/partlysecureapp%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```

   The first rule tells Apache not to perform any redirect if the path is **exactly** like your root path; the second redirects everything else to `https` (which will be handled by your `*:443` virtual host).

   (Note: you might want to serve `/site_media` without SSL as well)
3. Then you can simply add your WSGI alias; even if Django sends the user to a different page, Apache will ensure that page is served through SSL.

You final code would be something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/dev/python/django/partlysecureapp

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/partlysecureapp$ - [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^/site_media - [L,NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://127.0.0.1/partlysecureapp%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    ...
    WSGIScriptAlias /partlysecureapp /home/dev/python/django/partlysecureapp/partlysecureapp.wsgi
    Alias /site_media/ /home/dev/python/django/partlysecureapp/media/
</VirtualHost>
```

And your code for the SSL protected virtual host would be identical to the `mysecureapp` one (using `partlysecureapp` instead, of course; note also that you can have **both** apps running side-by-side, just pay attention to your `MEDIA` and `STATIC` paths).

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm also a developer-turned-sysadmin-by-necessity, so take my advice with a grain of salt. I'd suggest migrating this question to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/), where you might get better answers, but while it has an open bounty it can't be done.